# Loop for where clause sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to build the where clause in an update statement dynamic out of a result from one table

The result can looks like this (the primary key):

```
ID, 
ReferenceID, 
RefererenceNumber
```

This is the columns I will have in the where clause.

And in another table I have the values for every column in the primary key:

```
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
```

And my update statement looks like this:

```
set @sqlstring = 'update '+ @table +' set V = 1
WHERE  ;'
```

I think I have to do a variable which holds the where statement, but how will I build it up?

I'm new to SQL and I don't know where to start here

Comment: That is very unusual. If you add what you are trying to achieve we might find a better way

Comment: What I want to do is in an update statement dynamically and the columns I have to add to the where clause are the primary key columns . The number of the columns are different for each table. How can I make this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL, some DML statement for sample data, and desired results.

Comment: Please provide some context around your question. Generating dynamic UPDATE statements for any table with variable column list for variable number of values to be updated is an extreme edge case in tSQL development.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @S Nvarchar(max) = N'update '+ @table +' set V = 1 
WHERE ID = @ID and ReferenceID = @RID and RefererenceNumber = @RN;'

EXEC sp_executesql @S, N'@ID INT, @RID INT, @RN', 1, 2, 3
```